# Update the data of an existing table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need to make a table of searches made by the user in php. My code fails to encapsulate every new result in the table. I'd like you not to create a new table every time and delete the data, but to gradually add to the data already in the table. Also I have a problem with highlighting accents or special characters in php, how can I fix it? All my data is taken from a column (MySQL database = cherubini, table = lemmi) where it has already been normalized and therefore it works. In my code I have already tried both php and js, but in both cases they **conflict with the search results**. I am learning web development on my own by asking many questions about my problems, I hope they are useful. My PHP code doesn't work because there isn't my table in your own. You've to just to change database and table and two queries. The new table data must be added after the last element in the table. This is my code - it contains PHP code and MySQL connection - :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-1/512/search-icon.png">
    <title>Vocabulary searching</title>
    <style>
      body { margin-left: 20px; font-size: 20px; }
      a { text-decoration: none; margin-left: 180px; background: #00ff00; color: red; }
      table { border-collapse: collapse; }
      table, th, tr { border: 1px solid black; background: #00ff00;color: red; width: 336px;}
      .form { margin-top: 30px; }
      #text { width: 336px; }
      #button { visibility: hidden; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form" action="main.php" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Premi invio per cercare nel vocabolario Cherubini">
      <button type="submit" name="button" id="button"></button>
      <button type="submit" name="reset" id="reset">Pulisci la tabella</button>
    </form>
    <table><tr><th>Cronologia delle ricerche</th></tr></table>
    <?php
      error_reporting(0);
      ini_set('display_errors', 0);
      $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cherubini');
      $c = 0; $text2 = "";
      if(isset($_GET['button'])) {
        $text2 = $_GET['text'];
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM lemmi WHERE LemmaNo LIKE '%".$text2."%' ORDER BY LemmaNo");
        $count=$result->num_rows;
        if(empty($count)) {
          $r = $conn -> query("SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY ID");
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
            $history[$c] = $row['Parola'];
            echo "<tr><a href='main.php?text=".$row['Parola']."&button=' title='Cerca'>".$history[$c]."</a></tr>"."<br>"; $c++;
          } $c = 0; echo "<br>";
        }
        else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO history (Parola) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $text2);
        $stmt->execute(); $stmt->close();
        $r = $conn -> query("SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY ID");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
          $history[$c] = $row['Parola'];
          echo "<tr><a href='main.php?text=".$row['Parola']."&button=' title='Cerca'>".$history[$c]."</a></tr>"."<br>"; $c++;
        } $c = 0; echo "<br>"; }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $modifiedrawData = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', array($text2)).'/i', '<span style="background-color:yellow;"><b>$0</b></span>', $row['LemmaNo']);
          echo "<b>Lemma: </b>".$modifiedrawData."<br>";
          $modifiedrawData = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', array($text2)).'/i', '<span style="background-color:yellow;"><b>$0</b></span>', $row['Definizione']);
          echo "<b>Definizione: </b>".$modifiedrawData."<br><br>";
          $c++; } }
        if(isset($_GET['reset'])) { $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM history")->execute()->close(); }
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet has errors, could you correct them? Thanks. Could you clarify whether you are trying to add the row into the table in PHP or JS. I didn't understand that bit.

Comment: If I understand correctly, when a user types in a search term and it's been submitted to main.php you want that search term to join all previous ones in the table - is that whether they have been successfully matched with something in the database or not?

Comment: OK, most of the code you need is already there. The bit that is missing is a way of sending just the extra table row (rather than a whole table) and for that you need a way of getting main.php to respond and the JS to pick up one line. For this simple use case we can use AJAX. I can't do this immediately but should be able to put up an answer in a couple of hours. Meanwhile you might like to investigate XMLHttpRequests.

Comment: What have you tried to check where this error starts? Usually, this is either a Javascript problem (such that something in your browser is processed incorrect, such that the request is already sent with incorrect values) or a PHP problem (where all values are sent properly, but not handled properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like follows;

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Source : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

You can modify this to match with your table name, columns etc.